# Regular CW complexes are homeomorphic to delta complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to read Algebraic topology book by Hatcher. On page 535 he has stated that regular CW complexes are homeomorphic to $\Delta$-complexes. My question is that why is this true? Just an easy visible example is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a $\Delta$-complex structure by inducting on dimension of the cells: triangulate each closed disk as the cone on its boundary.